# How I can replace the object key with root, in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
 "data": {
    "abc": {
      "Id": "100",
      "print": "number",
      "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
      "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"



    },
    "xyz": {
      "Id": "123",
      "print": "number",
      "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
      "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"
    }
}
```

**Explanation**
I want to remove the root `data`, rest of the in side the `data` objects `abc`, `xyz` will remain as it is, in the 2nd step I want to replace the object value `number` with  `id` key , I want to to do this dynamically,

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "abc": {
      "number": "100",
      "print": "number",
      "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
      "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"
    },
    "xyz": {
      "number": "123",
      "print": "number",
      "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
      "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"

    }
 }
```

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on comments

Solution #3:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "array": { $objectToArray: "$data" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    {
        $addFields: { "array.v.number": "$array.v.Id" }
    },
    {
        $project: { "array.v.Id": 0 }                      // Optional 
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            array: { $push: "$array" }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Solution #2: If you do not wat to rename filed `Id` to `number` then the solution is simple:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: { $objectToArray: "$data" }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "abc" : {
        "Id" : "100",
        "print" : "number",
        "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
        "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"
    },
    "xyz" : {
        "Id" : "123",
        "print" : "number",
        "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
        "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"
    }
}
```

**OLD SOLUTION**

Try this

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
                        as: "item",
                        in: {
                            k: "$$item.k",
                            v: {
                                number: "$$item.v.Id",
                                print: "$$item.v.print",
                                uploadAt: "$$item.v.uploadAt",
                                servicesAt: "$$item.v.servicesAt"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```
{
    "abc" : {
        "number" : "100",
        "print" : "number",
        "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
        "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"
    },
    "xyz" : {
        "number" : "123",
        "print" : "number",
        "uploadAt" : "2021-22-01",
        "servicesAt" : "2020-01-12"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to go with 2nd sol, but I have multiple objects under ` abc`  `xyz` , but here I mention only 2, how I get the rest of them,? e.g I have 
`"xyz":{"id":"123","print":"number","uploadAt":"Date"}`, so how i can get rest of the object "uploadAt" etc

Comment: I just update my post, I really sorry for that, I have to explain that before I posted. I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for update the comment, this sol, I can follow, but what happens if I have 20--40 objects, I just mention now 4 of them.

Comment: The main issue is the renaming of `Id` to `number`, otherwise its just `v: "$$item.v"` inside `in`

Comment: if we do first  `v: "$$item.v" `  inside `in` and in next stage we can replace.? that could be work aroundwork?

Comment: Check Solution #3. Thats the max I could think of.